# Copy files from a list.txt, output error log

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I have read many posts covering copy and xcopy, but i am unable to get my command to work.

I aim is to create a batch file that will do the following;

Search a directory structure for a list of files 'names only' if found copy them to another directory. If not found create an error list.

The txt format of files I am looking for can be in any format however in testing i have a text file like this;

```
1603010853

1603020845

1603141400

1604061215
```

The files are .PDF or .TIF

The directory structure that I am searching is like this;

```
X:DEL>16>160314>1603141400.pdf
X:DEL>16>160301>1603010853.tif
```

I am struggling to get it to work as the list is not the full path.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in (File-list.txt) DO xcopy /S/E "c:Test\In%i" "c:out"
```

Thanks in advance
Fostersimported

Comment: This is like trying to carve a thanksgiving turkey with a spoon.  Possible, but a horrible idea with the tool at hand.  Can this not be done with any other tools?

Comment: Hi BJ Back,
yes it can but i do not know how, open to suggestions.

Comment: The command line you posted does not fit the example directory structure in terms of paths, so please update! Remember to double the `%` signs at `for` variables (`%i` --> `%%i`) when using it in a batch file. Do you want to search the target directory recursively (so sub-directories too)?

Comment: Hi aschipfl, yes i do want to search the target recursively that what i am struggling with. as the txt file just contains a list of file names not there location.

Thanks for the pointer on for the % with variables, at the moment i have just been testing the command in command prompt. to ensure it copies before i try and add it to a batch file. as I would also like it to output a errors.txt for files not copied/found

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, if tool doesn't matter much, I'd suggest going with the PowerShell script attached to [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/q/920344).  It seems to do everything you want (including logging errors).  You'd need only copypasta that into a text file, name it accordingly, and go from there.

Comment: Please insert the core approach of the linked post herein, because links might become inavailable in future!